# iOS error "[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

### The Error:

> ```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
> ```

### The Code:

`.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *history;
```

`.m`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:           (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSString *de = [[self.history objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"des"];
        NSString *dest = [de stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/rm_history.php?user_id=%@&destinations=%@",self.uID,dest]];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
         [self.history removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]
                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];   
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {   
        NSLog(@"create");
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

After setting a breakpoint to catch the error it stops at this line :

```
[self.history removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Any idea on what's causing the problem ?

Comment: What are you assigning to the `history` property? Where is it created.

Comment: `self.history`is probably declared immutable, so `NSArray`instead of `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @Volker No, you can see in the question that it is declared as a mutable array. That doesn't mean that the OP assigned a mutable array to it though

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist
It is declared on viewDidLoad : `self.history = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ds_history"];`

Comment: The error message informs you that you have assigned an `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray` to `self.history` at some point.  You need to find out where by looking at every place in your code where you set `self.history`. Note that if `dataDictionary` has an array assigned for the key `ds_history` it is up to you to either make sure it is actually an `NSMutableArray` or call `self.history = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ds_history"] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The fact that you declare `history` a `NSMutableArray` does *not* mean that only `NSMutableArray` can be assigned to it. It is possible to assign an immutable `NSArray` to the `history` if you are not careful. For example, this is what will happen if you serialize `NSMutableArray`, say, to JSON, and then deserialize it back to `NSMutableArray`: you would get an `NSArray` instead.

To avoid this issue, make sure that you always assign `history` either a `NSMutableArray` that you create, or a result of calling a `mutableCopy` on an `NSArray` that you receive from other parts of your code:

```
self.history = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ds_history"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it does NOT work and it gives me the same error

Comment: I've retried to implement it, it is working fine now, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because NSUserDefaults always returns an immutable object.

Please while retrieving Mutable object from NSUserDefaults please refer below code.

```
NSMutableArray *storeArray = [[defaultDefects objectForKey:@"defaultStoreDefects"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

***NSUserDefaults always returns an immutable object ***

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *history;
```

**--> For Save or Storing**

```
[userDefaults setObject:histrory forKey:@"des"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

**-->For Retrieving**

```
history = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"des"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `self.history` got casted to `NSArray` when it gets assigned.

Try the code below:

```
self.history = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ds_history"]];
```

Comment: You can cast a pointer all you want -- it doesn't change the object type.

Comment: Hot Licks - I should've said [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ds_history"] might be NSArray then. I didn't say [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ds_history"] is casted to NSArray tough.